# How to Know Content Private Use Area (PUA) of Font Awesome

Tags: web-applications, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, icons

I have been reading about [Font Awesome](http://gregoryloucas.github.com/Font-Awesome-More/#whats-new). I think it is a brilliant technique to be more efficient when we are using icons in our web applications.

I have a problem: when I want to add extension Social Icon from [Font Awesome](http://gregoryloucas.github.com/Font-Awesome-More/#whats-new), the problem is I don't know the Unicode (PUA) of the icon. For example, I want to use Icon-yahoo.

For example the PUA value for 'icon-legal' is "\f0e3".

Does anyone know how to find the PUA for every icon in [Font Awesome](http://gregoryloucas.github.com/Font-Awesome-More/#whats-new)?

Answer (score 1):

The Unicodes (PUA codes) for each icon are listed in the [Font Awesome CSS file](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css); see "Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA)..."

Answer (score 1):

With windows you can view them with "Character Map" application, as long as you've added FontAwesome to windows.  When you use Character Map you have to select the "Unicode" character set to see them.  You can also see them if you select either the "Japanese" or "Traditional Chinese" charter set also.  They won't display if any of the other character sets is chosen.